# PHP XML return stream being truncated from SQL 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, xml, file

I am having trouble getting a full XML result returned from an MS SQL 2008 R2 instance when using `sqlsrv_get_field` in PHP.

This is my code:

```
$statement = sqlsrv_query( $AnalysisConnection,$sql);

if( $statement === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($statement);

if($rows === false) {
    print ("no rows");
}
sqlsrv_fetch($statement);

$finalXML = sqlsrv_get_field($statement,0, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR));

//only do this if there is an xml to save.
if($finalXML) {
    file_put_contents('FILEFOLDER/FILENAME.xml', $finalXML);
    echo "<a href='FILEFOLDER/FILENAME.xml'>Download your XML</a>";
    //readfile($finalXML);
}
```

I have also tried using `fwrite()` with no success.

```
$handle = fopen('FILEFOLDER/FILENAME.xml','w');
stream_set_write_buffer($handle,0);

fwrite( $handle, $finalXML);
fclose($handle);
```

The raw data response in Fiddler is also showing the xml being truncated.  I am able to execute the stored procedure successfully in SQL.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you see this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371827/string-data-right-truncation-in-sqlsrv-php-driver-donut-hole ; it might be related.